# Spring boot throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: spring-boot, media-type

Here are the 2 mappings I have in my class:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/getUserDetails", consumes={"application/xml", "text/xml"}, produces={"application/xml", "text/xml"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "Response for user details", notes = "Gets response for user details", response = GetUserDetailsResponse.class )
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "returns response for user details")
@Timed(name = "http.userservice.getUserDetails", absolute = true)
public GetUserDetailsResponse getUserDetails(
    @RequestBody GetUserDetailsRequest request) throws ServiceException {
    GetUserDetailsResponse response = new GetUserDetailsResponse();
    String username = request.getUsername();
    User user = createUser(username);
    response.setUser(user);
    response.setUsername(username);
    return response;
}

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "hello world" , response = String.class )
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "hello world")
public String helloWorld() {
    return "hello world";
}
```

When I request `localhost:8080/`,
I am getting proper response i.e. "`hello world`". "`/`" is mapped to second method below.

But when I request for `localhost:8080/getUserDetails` with `POST` request, spring throws `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

Any idea?

Below is the xml data i am sending as part of POST request

```
<userDetailsRequest>
    <username>abc@cdk.com</username>
</userDetailsRequest>
```

Comment: Please show us what json you sent in the post request looks like.

Comment: Show how you're invoking the service. cURL? Postman? Are you setting Content-Type on the request?

Comment: localhost:8080/getUserDetails